# PlaceHolder - how to replce placeholder in aspx?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-placeholder

I have a PlaceHolder component in my project, but I want to place it in right part of the page, as now it's placed in the top. Is there any opportunity to change it's alighn?

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server" Visible="true">  
        <dx:ReportParametersPanel ID="reportParameterPanel1" runat="server" ReportViewerID="ReportViewer1">    
        </dx:ReportParametersPanel>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should enclose the entire `Place Holder` code in a `Div` and set the `Style` of the Div to `Float:Right`.

For more controlled positioning of the Div, use:

```
Position:Absolute;
```